# unable to load jquery into lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, jquery

I am trying to import jquery 2.2.4 in lightning component but i am facing issue 
with error code
`Custom Script Eval error [SecureDOMEvent: [object Event]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }]`

I Enabled Stricter Content Security Policy but still no luck. Do we have any alternative approach for this?

Comment: How did you import the script?

Comment: @sfdcfox <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jquery224}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}"/> is my script to load

Comment: I just tested this in my org, jQuery 2.2.4 seems to be working just fine. Perhaps you're doing an illegal operation in your script? Can you please include what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Had this exact same issue and by using Locker Console, I identified my jQuery static resource was at fault.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console

Solution for me was to create a new static resource from https://code.jquery.com/

Hope it works for you

Comment: which version ?

Comment: core 3.3.1 slim minified.

Comment: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js